# Understanding try_for_each in RUST?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am new to Rust and until now I have very hard time understanding the compiler errors. In this specific case I have a fallible function that I want to apply to every element of the iterator. I have try using `try_for_each` but compiler keeps giving me error `the trait bound (): Try is not satisfied` . I have no idea how to resolve this issue. I also wonder how people usually get idea of Rust errors, because I feel it is very hard to decode?

Structure of my code is as follows

```
iter.try_for_each(|x| let some_var= fallible_function(*x)?; do_something_with_var(some_var);)
```

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example, preferably with a link to the playground, and the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: Presumably it's upset that you aren't returning `Ok` from the closure. Try with `Ok(())` at the tail of the closure.

Answer (score 2):

try_for_each take a closure/function that return a Try type (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html), like Option or Result, where you can apply the `?` operator, just like you did with `fallible_function(*x)?`, so if your function return an Result, the closure must return an Result, but your closure end with nothing, so you must return an Infaillible value like `Result::Ok` (you could return a Residual, https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FromResidual.html, like `Option::None`, but the iterator will always return after the first iteration).

I'm entering a bit too much into the detail on how the `?` operator work, if you want to know more about the inner working of it and how it can enable you to make your own types for advanced control flow I would highly suggest you to look into the Try trait, but other than that yeah you just need to return `Ok(())` or `Some(())`, depending on what the faillible function return.